# Perfect fit of ggplot2 plot in plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, spline

I want to plot a restricted cubic spline as main plot and add a box-and-whisker plot to show the variation of the X variable. However, the lower hinge (x=42), the median (x=51), and the upper hinge(x=61) did not fit perfectly with the corresponding grid line of the main plot.

```
library(Hmisc)
library(rms)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

data(pbc)
d <- pbc
rm(pbc)
d$status <- ifelse(d$status != 0, 1, 0)

dd = datadist(d)
options(datadist='dd')

f <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~  rcs(age, 4), data=d)
p <- Predict(f, fun=exp)
df <- data.frame(age=p$age, yhat=p$yhat, lower=p$lower, upper=p$upper)

### 1st PLOT: main plot
(g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=age, y=yhat)) + geom_line(size=1))

# CI
(g <- g + geom_ribbon(data=df, aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), alpha=0.5, linetype=0, fill='#FFC000'))

# white background
(g <- g + theme_bw())

# X-axis
(breaks <- round(boxplot.stats(p[,"age"])$stats))
(g <- g + scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks, limits=range(p[,"age"]), labels=round(breaks)))
(g <- g + xlab("Age"))

# Y-Achse
(g <- g + ylab("Hazard Ratio"))

# size and color of axis
(g <- g + theme(axis.line = element_line(color='black', size=1)))
(g <- g + theme(axis.ticks = element_line(color='black', size=1)))

(g <- g + theme( plot.background = element_blank() ))
#(g <- g + theme( panel.grid.major = element_blank() ))
(g <- g + theme( panel.grid.minor = element_blank() ))
(g <- g + theme( panel.border = element_blank() ))

### 2nd PLOT: box whisker plot
describe(df$age, digits=0)
round(range(df$age))
(gg <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=1, y=age)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA, size=1) + coord_flip())
(gg <- gg + theme( axis.line=element_blank() )) #
(gg <- gg + theme( axis.text.x=element_blank() ))
(gg <- gg + theme( axis.text.y=element_blank() ))
(gg <- gg + theme( axis.ticks=element_blank() ))
(gg <- gg + theme( axis.title.x=element_blank() ))
(gg <- gg + theme( axis.title.y=element_blank() ))
(gg <- gg + theme( panel.background=element_blank() ))
(gg <- gg + theme( panel.border=element_blank() )) #
(gg <- gg + theme( legend.position="none" )) #
(gg <- gg + theme( panel.grid.major=element_blank() )) #
(gg <- gg + theme( panel.grid.minor=element_blank() ))
(gg <- gg + theme( plot.background=element_blank() ))
(gg <- gg + theme( plot.margin = unit( c(0,0,0,0), "in" ) ))

(gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(70,77,84), expand=c(0,0)) )

### FINAL PLOT: put box whisker plot in main plot
(final.gg <- g + annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(gg),  ymin=2.4, ymax=2.6))
```

1. What do I have to change for the perfect fit?
2. Is there a better for a automatized alignment of the y-position of the
   box-and-whisker?

[image]

**UPDATE #1**
Thanks for your answer! Below you can see my example with your code. However, as you can see, the lower hinge, the median, and the upper hinge still do not fit. What is going wrong?

```
library(Hmisc)
library(rms)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

data(pbc)
d <- pbc
rm(pbc, pbcseq)
d$status <- ifelse(d$status != 0, 1, 0)

dd = datadist(d)
options(datadist='dd')

f <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~  rcs(age, 4), data=d)
p <- Predict(f, fun=exp)
df <- data.frame(age=p$age, yhat=p$yhat, lower=p$lower, upper=p$upper)

### 1st PLOT: main plot
(breaks <- boxplot.stats(p[,"age"])$stats)
g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=age, y=yhat)) + geom_line(size=1) +
     geom_ribbon(data=df, aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), alpha=0.5, linetype=0, fill='#FFC000') +
     theme_bw() +
     scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks) +
     xlab("Age") +
     ylab("Hazard Ratio") +
     theme(axis.line = element_line(color='black', size=1),
           axis.ticks = element_line(color='black', size=1),
           plot.background = element_blank(),
           # panel.border = element_blank(),
           panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

### 2nd PLOT: box whisker plot
gg <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=1, y=age)) + 
     geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA, size=1) + 
     scale_y_continuous(breaks=breaks) +
     ylab(NULL) +
     coord_flip()  + 
     # theme_bw() +
     theme(axis.line=element_blank(), 
           # axis.text.x=element_blank(),
           axis.text.y=element_blank(),
           axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
           axis.title=element_blank(),
           # panel.background=element_blank(),
           panel.border=element_blank(),
           # panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
           panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
           # plot.background=element_blank(),
           plot.margin = unit( c(0,0,0,0), "in" ), 
           axis.ticks.margin = unit(0, "lines"),
           axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "cm"))

### FINAL PLOT: put box whisker plot in main plot
(final.gg <- g + annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(gg),  ymin=2.4, ymax=2.6))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding the picture!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Minor edit: Updating to ggplot2 2.0.0**
`axis.ticks.margin` is deprecated

In the boxplot, even though you have set various elements to `element_blank` and margins to zero, default spaces remain resulting in the misalignment. These spaces belong to:

- axis.ticks.length
- xlab

In the code below, I've re-arranged your code somewhat (I hope that's okay), and commented out some lines of code so that it can be seen that the two plots do align. I've also set the breaks in the two plot to un-rounded `breaks` (min and max values, hinges, and the median).

```
# X-axis
(breaks <- boxplot.stats(p[,"age"])$stats)

### 1st PLOT: main plot
g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=age, y=yhat)) + geom_line(size=1) +
     geom_ribbon(data=df, aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), alpha=0.5, linetype=0, fill='#FFC000') +
     theme_bw() +
     scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks) +
     xlab("Age") +
     ylab("Hazard Ratio") +
     theme(axis.line = element_line(color='black', size=1),
       axis.ticks = element_line(color='black', size=1),
       plot.background = element_blank(),
      # panel.border = element_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

### 2nd PLOT: box whisker plot
gg <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=1, y=age)) + 
      geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA, size=1) + 
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=breaks) +
      xlab(NULL) +
      coord_flip()  + 
     # theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.line=element_blank(), 
         # axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
          axis.title=element_blank(),
         # panel.background=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank(),
         # panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
         # plot.background=element_blank(),
          plot.margin = unit( c(0,0,0,0), "in" ), 
         # axis.ticks.margin = unit(0, "lines"),
          axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "cm"))

### FINAL PLOT: put box whisker plot in main plot
(final.gg <- g + annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(gg),  ymin=2.4, ymax=2.6))
```

[image]

You should note that ggplot's method for calculating the hinges differs slightly from the method used by `boxplot.stats`.

```
# ggplot's hinges
bp = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=1, y=age)) + 
      geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA, size=1)
bpData = ggplot_build(bp)
bpData$data[[1]][1:5]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Do you have any idea how you can plot the box-and-whisker plot with a fix height and at a fix position relative to the main plot? Like it is know, I would need to adapt manually the height and y-position depending on the predictor on the x-axis.

Comment: @Gurkenhals Yes, but not using `annotation_custom`. See the alternative answer. I would position the boxplot outside the main plot pane. Thus, its position is fixed. I use the gtable functions to do so. The height of the boxplot panel can be adjusted relative to the height of main plot panel. A similar effect can be achieved using viewports (from grid package).

Comment: 1 year later the script runs without an error but does not plot anything. Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure. When I run the code, I get the chart as displayed. I'm using versions: R 3.3.1; ggplot2 2.1.0; gridExtra 2.2.1

Answer (score 3):

Alternative answer using `gtable` functions to position the boxplot outside the main plot. The height of the box plot can be adjusted using the "h" parameter

```
library(rms)

# Data
data(pbc)
d <- pbc
rm(pbc)
d$status <- ifelse(d$status != 0, 1, 0)

dd = datadist(d)
options(datadist='dd')

f <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~  rcs(age, 4), data=d)
p <- Predict(f, fun=exp)
df <- data.frame(age=p$age, yhat=p$yhat, lower=p$lower, upper=p$upper)

# X-axis
breaks <- boxplot.stats(p[,"age"])$stats

# Main plot
MP <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=age, y=yhat)) + geom_line(size=1) +
     geom_ribbon(data=df, aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), alpha=0.5, linetype=0, fill='#FFC000') +
     theme_bw() +
     scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks) +
     xlab("Age") +
     ylab("Hazard Ratio") +
     theme(axis.line = element_line(color='black', size=1),
       axis.ticks = element_line(color='black', size=1),
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

# Boxplot
BP <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(1), y=age)) + 
      geom_boxplot(width = 1, outlier.shape=NA, size=1) + 
      geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .3), size = 1) +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=breaks) +
      coord_flip()  + 
      theme_bw() +
      theme(panel.border=element_blank(),
            panel.grid=element_blank())

####  Set up the grobs and gtables  here
library(gtable)
library(grid)

h = 1/15  # height of boxplot panel relative to main plot panel

# Get ggplot grobs
gMP = ggplotGrob(MP)
BPg = ggplotGrob(BP)
BPg = gtable_filter(BPg, "panel")  # from the boxplot, extract the panel only

# In the main plot, get position of panel in the layout
pos = gMP$layout[gMP$layout$name == "panel", c('t', 'l')]

# In main plot, set height for boxplot
gMP$heights[pos$t-2] = unit(h,  "null")

# Add boxplot to main plot
gMP = gtable_add_grob(gMP, BPg, t=pos$t-2, l=pos$l)

# Add small space
gMP$heights[pos$t-1] = unit(5,  "pt")

# Draw it 
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gMP)
```

[image]